# How to configure amplify-authenticator signIn for site headers?

Tags: angular, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I'm using the latest Amplify Authenticator for Angular [here](https://docs.amplify.aws/ui/auth/authenticator/q/framework/angular).

As suggested I can use the following code so I can have a sign-in page:

```
<amplify-authenticator *ngIf="authState !== 'signedin'"></amplify-authenticator>

<div *ngIf="authState === 'signedin' && user" class="App">
    <amplify-sign-out></amplify-sign-out>
    <div>Hello, {{user.username}}</div>
    <!-- This is where you application template code goes -->  
</div>
```

That's working fine. However, I'm having a problem when I use this in a header component in Angular as I want to have that Sign Out button at the header. Whenever I put the `<amplify-sign-out>` which works but once I log out the login form shows up in the header (because of the `<amplify-authenticator>` part).

Any workaround that you can suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out that to implement authentication for Amplify there are two options-- UI libraries or use authentication methods via the Auth class.

I've been using the UI libraries in the question above. [Auth class](https://aws-amplify.github.io/amplify-js/api/classes/authclass.html) can be used for more customised applications.